# *.ANE for extend iPhone app i receive "ld: absolute addressing" ERROR when add it to my Main Flex Project and compile it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, apache-flex, flash-builder, air-native-extension

I'm coding an extension (ANE) for iPhone that read the contact list.
I receive an error when add the .ane to my Flash Builder Project and compile it.
I compiled the Objective-c code in a *.a lib without problems.
I compiled the .ane without errors.

This is the error when i add the .ane at the main Flex Project:

```
Error occurred while packaging the application:

ld: absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) used in _getContatti from
/var/folders/j9/j9OzOTqhGJGpr2m87bnYEU+++TQ/-Tmp-/888e0e80-9ef5-4d2a-9e34-
c01545b25bfc/mylib.library.com.a(ExtensionMyLibIOSNative.o) 
not allowed in slidable image. Use '-read_only_relocs suppress' to enable text 
relocs
Compilation failed while executing : ld64
```

In Xcode i have arleady set "Enable Linking With Shared Libraries" to "NO" in Build Settings.
This is the Objective-c code that cause the error:

```
FREObject getContatti(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[]) {

FREObject nome_visualizzato;
FREObject nome_visualizzatoPrimario;
FREObject nome_visualizzatoAlternativo;

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

FREObject arrayContatti;
FRENewObject((const uint8_t*)"Vector.<extension.MyLibrary.entity.Contatto>", 0, NULL, &arrayContatti, NULL);
FRESetArrayLength(arrayContatti, nPeople);


for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
    CFStringRef first = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    CFStringRef last = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    CFStringRef company = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);
    -- DO SOMETHING --
}
    return result;
}
```

It work if i comment\remove the lines:

```
CFStringRef first = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
CFStringRef last = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
CFStringRef company = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if AddressBook framework (and possibly AddressBookUI, if you are using any views from AddressBook) is included in your project in 'link binary with libraries' (you can find it here: http://wordpress.rcntech.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Xcode4_Adding_Existing_Framework3.png)
   Try setting 'enable linking with shared libraries' to yes (if it is set to 'no')
   Add required frameworks to platform options when compiling the ane (if they are not included in air already)

Alternatively, since you are trying to access AddressBook, you can check this extension:
https://github.com/memeller/ContactEditor